# Shopify API - Response code = 429. Response message = Too Many Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify

I am working with Shopify API with rails. But I am getting an error. 
I don't know why this error showing.

```
ActiveResource::ClientError: Failed.  Response code = 429.  Response message = Too Many Requests.
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/api-call-limit . Here is my code:

```
cycle = 0.5

product_count = ShopifyAPI::Product.count
nb_pages      = (product_count / 250.0).ceil

start_time = Time.now
1.upto(nb_pages) do |page|
    unless page == 1
        stop_time = Time.now
        processing_duration = stop_time - start_time
        wait_time = (cycle - processing_duration).ceil
        sleep wait_time if wait_time > 0
        start_time = Time.now
    end


    if product_list == 'all'
        products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find( :all, :params => { :limit => 250, :page => page } )
    elsif product_list.include? 'category'
        product_list.slice! "category"
        products = ShopifyAPI::Product.where(:collection_id => product_list, :limit => 250, :page => page )
    else
        products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: {ids: product_list})
    end

    products.each do |product|
        variants = Array.new
        metafields = Array.new
        product.variants.each do |variant|
            variants << variant
            metafields << product.metafields
            if variant.title.include? "+"
                next
            end
            quantity.each_with_index  do |q, i|

                unless customer_tag.to_s.strip.empty?
                    variants << {
                                    "title"=>"c #{variant.title} #{q}+",
                                    "price"=> price_calculate(calculation_type, discount_value[i], variant.price),
                                    "inventory_policy"=>"deny",
                                    "option1"=>"c #{variant.option1} #{q}+",
                                    "option2"=>nil,
                                    "option3"=>nil,
                                    "created_at"=> Time.now,
                                    "updated_at"=> Time.now,
                                    "taxable"=> variant.taxable,
                                    "inventory_quantity"=>1,
                                    "weight"=> variant.weight,
                                    "weight_unit"=> "#{variant.weight_unit}",
                                    "requires_shipping"=> variant.requires_shipping
                                }
                else
                    variants << {
                                    "title"=>"#{variant.title} #{q}+",
                                    "price"=> price_calculate(calculation_type, discount_value[i], variant.price),
                                    "inventory_policy"=>"deny",
                                    "option1"=>"#{variant.option1} #{q}+",
                                    "option2"=>nil,
                                    "option3"=>nil,
                                    "created_at"=> Time.now,
                                    "updated_at"=> Time.now,
                                    "taxable"=> variant.taxable,
                                    "inventory_quantity"=>1,
                                    "weight"=> variant.weight,
                                    "weight_unit"=> "#{variant.weight_unit}",
                                    "requires_shipping"=> variant.requires_shipping
                                }
                end

            end

        end

        unless customer_tag.to_s.strip.empty?
            metafields << {
                            "namespace": "customer_tag",
                            "key": "#{customer_tag}",
                            "value": "#{customer_tag}",
                            "value_type": "string"
                        }
        end

        product.variants = variants
        product.metafields = metafields
        product.save
    end
end
```

Why it's showing Shopify API Limit error ? I made only 1 API call by following their tutorial. Please any idea ..

Comment: Did you create a `cleanup.rb` with your APIKEY, PASSWORD, and SHOPNAME as instructed on that page you linked?

Comment: I used this gems https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app. Others working perfectly.

Comment: Are you using your own API key? See [shopify_app - Managing Api Keys](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app#managing-api-keys)

Comment: Yes. I have configured this app correctly

Comment: Well, then I only have 2 suggestions: 1. make sure your app isn't making many calls, and 2. you should probably contact Shopify about the issue on your API Access

Comment: Shopify API has a limit. Go through this - https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/api-call-limit

Comment: @HymnZ I have gone through this tutorial. help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/api-call-limit please read my post. Thanks

Comment: Use this gem to automatically backoff/retry requests to avoid the API rate limit. https://github.com/iloveitaly/shopify_api_extensions/

Answer (score 0):

Shopify follows leaky bucket algorithm, which means that it allows infrequent bursts of calls. But you need to average 0.5 seconds/call. These are the methods corresponding to different API calls in your script:

1. `ShopifyAPI::Product.find`
2. `product.metafields`
3. `product.save`

Only the first call is being managed using the timing manager that you have written above. The next two calls will also need to be a part of it.